# Removing columns in python

Tags: python, csv

Having a comma-separated file with around 50 columns and several rows, I need to remove all columns that are always 0 (i.e all values in that column are zero).

The file is read with the following piece of code:

```
with open('data.txt', 'rb') as f:
    reader.csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        print row


0 0.1 0.3 0.4 0
0 0.2 0.5 0.3 0
0 0.7 0.9 0.2 0
```

How one can exactly remove columns (that are 0) from this memory structure. It would be more better, if there is no re-writing and re-reading to another temporary csv file to achieve this.

Comment: Need to remove columns

Comment: How many rows are we talking about here? This is easiest to handle by  reading it all into memory first.

Comment: Number of rows are around 300.

Comment: Do you know ahead of time which columns are all zeros and need to be removed? Or do you have to determine that dynamically?

Comment: Yes. I have to determine that dynamically.

Comment: How about this: 1) transpose the matrix, 2) remove empty rows, 3) transpose it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read in all rows (mapping all the values to floats), transform to columns using `zip(*rows)`, only keep any that are have non-zero values using `any()`, transform back to rows using `zip(*columns)`:

```
with open('data.txt', 'rb') as f:
    rows = list(map(float, row) for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=','))

rows = zip(*[col for col in zip(*rows) if any(col)])
```

The latter step as a demonstration:

```
>>> rows = [[0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0], [0, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0], [0, 0.7, 0.9, 0.2, 0]]
>>> zip(*[col for col in zip(*rows) if any(col)])
[(0.1, 0.3, 0.4), (0.2, 0.5, 0.3), (0.7, 0.9, 0.2)]
```

Comment: Isn't this possible in python do it all in memory instead of writing to CSV file and re-reading it again. Because I need to process this data further.

Comment: @Shahzad: This was all in memory. I thought you wanted it written to a CSV again; just remove the writing stage if you don't want that.